# SqlBulkCopying Data To many Tables, each time returning generated to be used in the next insert

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, bulkinsert

So I have the following requirement

**BEGIN TRANSACTION**

1. BULK INSERT records into TableA
2. Get ID of recently added rows in TableA, using LINQ to update associated records in memory
3. BULK INSERT updated records into TableB
4. Get ID of recently added rows in TableB, using LINQ to update associated records in memory
5. BULK INSERT updated records into TableC
6. Get ID of recently added rowsin TableC, using LINQ to update associated records in memory
7. BULK INSERT updated records into TableF
8. Get ID of recently added rows in TableF, using LINQ to update associated records in memory
9. BULK INSERT updated records into TableD
10. Get ID of recently added rows in TableF, using LINQ to update associated records in memory
11. Finally, BULK INSERT the records into TableE

**COMMIT TRANSACTION**

I simply do a bulkcopy to each table, each time following that with a select statement to return the generated ids, map those to the next set of records to go, and then repeat. But I wanted to know a better way to handle this situation as it currently takes a while to run this( **about 20 minutes for an average of 500 records per SQL BULK COPY Statement in the algorithm above**). I thought of calling Refresh() on my DbContext object(I have ORM setup, but I use SQLBulkCopy for the bulk inserts), and then access the generated IDS that way but I don't think it is a sound idea either. What can I do to improve this please? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `about 20 minutes for an average of 500 records per load` that is very unhealthy. If all you want is insert 1000 records into 5 tables, and you're willing to have that take a few seconds, EF is well-suited for that. Investigate, why its taking so long.

Comment: Better, improve, ... kinda hard if we can't see the current process. I suspect it should be possible to pinpoint some inefficient lines in your code.

Comment: There is really not much else other than what I have above.

Comment: Of course there is. These words don't run. If you say _20 minutes for an average of 500 records per load_ it makes me wonder what exactly happens there. How do you use EF, what are the contexts' lifetimes, when and where do you fetch records, are you smart with switching off tracking, how do SQLBulkCopy and EF cooperate, ...? It's like you ask us to proof-read a text, but all we get is a summary.